# Difference between reflexive pronouns and by + reflexive pronouns

Tags: difference, reflexive-pronouns

I'd like to know what's the difference between for example myself and by myself.
it would be great if you made some example to be easier to understand.
Thank you everyone.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> I did it myself.  → I didn't call anybody else.
> I did it by myself. → Nobody else helped me do it.

The first says that the speaker did it.  He might have had help, but the main thing is that he did it.

The second means that he did it without help.

Comment: You should use your examples in a larger context. As written I can't see much difference. Honestly, "I do it myself" does not sound right, perhaps use "I *will* do it myself" or "I *did* it myself".

Comment: @user3169: I decided to use the past tense.  I'll admit, it sounds much more natural.